# error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [aplikasi_scan_plat_nomor] lib\screen\home.dart:10)

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 2):

key can be nullable, you can do

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

Or just

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});
```

And if you make it required it will be

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({required Key key}) : super(key: key);
```